# What does "get" in "gets the skin" mean?

Tags: meaning-in-context, verbs

This context comes from the movie "Midnight Run". It's a scene where one of the characters uncuffs the other.

"Thanks, 'cause it's starting to cut into my wrists. Thank you.
It **gets** the skin after a while."

15. to hit, strike, or wound: *The bullet got him in the leg*.(Random House Kernerman Webster's)

d. To annoy or irritate: *What got me was his utter lack of initiative.*(American Heritage® Dictionary of the English Language)

The second example seems to refer to a person's emotions although **skin can also be irritated.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, in this example "gets" means "irritates". The words "*get*" and "*gets*" are used in many senses, it is perhaps one of the most flexible words in English, after "*Be*".